# Filter with startsWith with multiple object keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a search `component` and everything works well. But I have a question. How do I make the following code dynamic?

```
function isMatch(obj) {
  let result =  obj.code.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase()) || 
  obj.description.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase()) 
  return  result 
}
```

Now the search is carried out on two `keys` of the `object`, but I need to set it dynamically. For example:

```
serachKey = ['code', 'description', ...]
```

Comment: `obj['code']` is equivalent to `obj.code` so you can loop over the search keys, testing each as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach you can try:

```js
const searchKey = ['code', 'description'];

function isMatch(obj, search) {
  return searchKey.some(key => obj[key] && obj[key].toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase()));
}

const mySearch = "testing";
const myObj = {"code": "some code", "description": "testing code"};

console.log(isMatch(myObj, mySearch));
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks.